# Error java.lang.NumberFormatException if i try to insert 2 words into a single string (Java)

Tags: java, collections, hashset, treeset

Error java.lang.NumberFormatException if i try to insert 2 words into a single string (Java) !!

ERROR shown is:

> Enter item Chicken rice Enter amount(Dinar)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
> string: "rice"    at
> java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)   at
> java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:999)     at
> Sampleproject1/t4.Main.main(Main.java:65)

```
import java.util.*;

class Expense implements Comparable<Expense>{
    
    String expenseCategory;
    Integer amount;
    
    
    public String getExpenseCategory() {
        return expenseCategory;
    }
    public void setExpenseCategory(String expenseCategory) {
        this.expenseCategory = expenseCategory;
    }
    public Integer getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }   
    
    public Expense(String expC , Integer amount) {
        this.expenseCategory=expC;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
        
    public String toString() {
        return expenseCategory+ " " +amount;
    }
        
    public int compareTo(Expense e) {
        if(amount>e.amount){    
            return 1;    
        }else if(amount<e.amount){    
            return -1;    
        }else{    
        return 0;    
        } 
    }
}

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        TreeSet<Expense> set1 = new TreeSet<Expense>();

        int tamount=0;
        
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter item");
            String expC = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter amount(Dinar)");
            String amt = sc.next();
            tamount = tamount + Integer.valueOf(amt);
            set1.add(new Expense(expC,Integer.valueOf(amt)));
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue(yes/no):");
            String cond = sc.next();
            if(cond.equals("no")) {
                break;
            }else {continue;}
        }
        System.out.println("Total dinar required is:");
        System.out.println("Category    Amount(Dinar)");
        Iterator x = set1.descendingIterator();
            
        while(x.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(x.next());
        }
                
        System.out.println("Total amount needed in Dinar:"+ tamount);
        System.out.println("Total amount needed in Rupees:"+ tamount*18.565);   
    }       
}
```

```
Output should be like :
Enter item
Fried Rice
Enter amount(Dinar)
20
Do you want to continue(yes/no):
yes
Enter item
Chicken Lollipop
Enter amount(Dinar)
25
Do you want to continue(yes/no):
yes
Enter item
Coffee
Enter amount(Dinar)
5
Do you want to continue(yes/no):
no
Total dinar required is:
Item           Amount(Dinar)  
Chicken Lollipop25             
Fried Rice     20             
Coffee         5              
Total amount needed in Dinar: 50
Total amount needed in Rupees: 928.25
```

IF I USE nextLine(); some inputs are SKIPPED !!

[image: *I]

Comment: Please refer to the documentation. [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) reads *tokens* separated by space. If you want to read the whole line `Fried Rice` then you need to use [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead

Comment: but if i use nextLine() the while loop skips some inputs

Comment: Then you need to read this: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from your examples that you intend for the 'enter' key to be the separator between input. However, out of the box, scanner treats *any whitespace* as the separator. Simply tell it you only want newlines. Immediately after `new Scanner(System.in)`:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\R");
```

`\\R` is regexp-ese for "any newline variant".

Answer (score -2):

Fixed it by adding nextLine() for all the statements